# Create new Measure based on 2 fact

Tags: powerbi, dax

Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Show data:

[image]

I need to get the result bellow:

**Case 1** (no filter)

Get only one row: sum of V1 , sum V2 and name of the related value of sum V1

[image]

**Case 2**: filter name in (A,B)

Get only one row: sum of V1 , sum filtred V2 (3+4) and name of the related value of sum V1

[image]

I tried to create this mesure

Measure V2 = CALCULATE( SUM(fact2[V2]),REMOVEFILTERS(dim_p[name]))

But I think that I need to add some details

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

@mods: sorry, posting as guest does not provide me option to “comment”, so I am “answering“ ..

@Emna:
Usually, using `key` and `fk1` and `fk2` connected to `key` helps to match the facts with the same key.

What is the logic between the keys in fact1 and fact2 and the related values?
e.g. is there any value in fact1 for A..D and, vice versa, any value in fact2 for E? And what about F, etc.? And how are they connected to each other? (With the connection shown in the first picture, there is no overlapping/matching between fact1 and fact2)

In general, when filtering the name for A and B, DAX will no show the result for E. Your measure sums up fact2 with any filter to the name removed. Assuming there are no other active filters, it basically sums up all V2 in fact2 regardless any filtering of the name.

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity

I'm agree with the last remark "when filtering the name for A and B, DAX will not show the result for E". but I need to create another column or modify my measure in order to force the search for the name having the value V1 not blank

Comment: To help you, need to understand what is the (intended) relation between fact1 and fact2.  See the questions mentioned.

Comment: If you want the solution for the exact case, need to create another “key” list, not connected, but used as slicer for fact2. Define measure to sum up fact2 filtered by this second key list list. Deactivate the connection between first key list and fact2. Show table visual filtered by your key list selected for E, where you show fact1 and the measure.

Comment: Is this kind of an assignment/exercise?  

Good luck!